# JavaScript function not working as desired

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working with HTML, JavaScript and CSS. The function objective is to create a border-radius attribute in a div element(id="surface"), and assign the value typed in inputs texts(class="chars_1") to it.

HTML

```html
  <div id="container"> 
            <div class="input_wrapper" id="input_wrapper_tl">
                <input type="text" id="input_tl" class="chars_1" value="0" onkeypress="changeSize()">
            </div>
            <div class="input_wrapper" id="input_wrapper_tr">
                <input type="text" id="input_tr" class="chars_1" value="0" onkeypress="changeSize()">
            </div>
            <div class="input_wrapper" id="input_wrapper_br">
                <input type="text" id="input_br" class="chars_1" value="0" onkeypress="changeSize()">
            </div>
            <div class="input_wrapper" id="input_wrapper_bl">
                <input type="text" id="input_bl" class="chars_1" value="0" onkeypress="changeSize()">
            </div>
            <div id="surface">
                <textarea id="code" readonly="readonly"></textarea>
                <div id="options">
                    <input type="checkbox" checked="true" id="opt_webkit">
                    <label for="opt_webkit"> Webkit</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" checked="true" id="opt_gecko">
                    <label for="opt_gecko"> Gecko</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" checked="true" id="opt_css3">
                    <label for="opt_css3"> CSS3</label>
                </div>
            </div>
```

JavaScript Function

```js
function changeSize(){
  var surface = document.getElementById("surface");
  var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("chars_1");  
  var total = 0;
    for(var x = 0; x == 3; x++){
    total += Number(inputs[x].value);
  }
  surface.style.borderRadius = String(total)+"px";
}
```

First I selected both elements and assigned it to these 2 variable "surface" and "inputs". "total" being used in the "for structure" to go through every input element and select every value, and afterward convert to Number to the "total" variable.

The idea is to assign to the border-radius attribute the total variable value, which will be converted to a string so it can be recognized as a value.

Comment: What part of it isn't working? If you debug and stop on the line that sets the border radius, what are the values of all your variables, and if you try the same statement in the chrome console, does it work?

Comment: what do you really want from your code, i didn't get your question

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a title that is more descriptive of your specific question. Currently it describes almost every question tagged [javascript] on this site :). See [ask] for tips.

Comment: Why did you revert the snippet I made you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Have a border
2. Fix the for loop   `for (var x = 0; x < inputs.length; x++) {`

Here is an upgraded version

```js
const changeSize = (e) => {
  const tgt = e.target; // which input
  if (tgt.classList.contains("chars_1")) { // ah, one of those
    let total = [...document.querySelectorAll(".chars_1")].reduce(
      (sum, input) => { 
        const val = input.value;
        sum += val.trim() === "" || isNaN(val) ? 0 : +val; // only add if a number
        return sum;
      }, 0);
    console.log(String(total) + "px")
    document.getElementById("surface").style.borderRadius = String(total) + "px";
  }
};
window.addEventListener("load", () => { // when page loads
  document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("input", changeSize);
});
```

```css
#surface {
  border: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="input_wrapper" id="input_wrapper_tl">
    <input type="text" id="input_tl" class="chars_1" value="0">
  </div>
  <div class="input_wrapper" id="input_wrapper_tr">
    <input type="text" id="input_tr" class="chars_1" value="0">
  </div>
  <div class="input_wrapper" id="input_wrapper_br">
    <input type="text" id="input_br" class="chars_1" value="0">
  </div>
  <div class="input_wrapper " id="input_wrapper_bl ">
    <input type="text" id="input_bl " class="chars_1" value="0">
  </div>
  <div id="surface">
    <textarea id="code" readonly="readonly"></textarea>
    <div id="options">
      <input type="checkbox" checked="true" id="opt_webkit">
      <label for="opt_webkit"> Webkit</label>
      <input type="checkbox" checked="true" id="opt_gecko">
      <label for="opt_gecko"> Gecko</label>
      <input type="checkbox" checked="true" id="opt_css3">
      <label for="opt_css3"> CSS3</label>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var x = 0; x == 3; x++)
```

that loop doesn't even execute,
change x==3 on x<3 or whatever you want to achive.

And I guess you must have border to change it's radious